# how to string.format multiple column names with X length of column in C# SQL query

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to SELECT {0}, {1},...FROM a table but have trouble when trying to string.format the column names which I have, but not sure how many I have. Here is what I have so far.

```
String query = "SELECT";
for (int i = 0; i < requestedColumns.Count; i++)
{
    query += " {" + i.ToString() + "},";
}

query = query.Remove(query.Length - 1) + " WHERE id=@id LIMIT 1";
```

Here is where I run into trouble:

```
for (int i = 0; i < requestedColumns.Count; i++)
{
    query = String.Format(query,requestedColumns[i]);
}
```

This is the error I get:

> Index(zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and lesss than the size of the argument list.

I am not sure how to format the syntax and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var query = "SELECT " +string.Join(",", requestedColumns) + " WHERE id=@id LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`string.Join`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join)

```
var query = "SELECT " +string.Join(",", requestedColumns);
```

Comment: thank you, would this be safe in terms of protection from SQL injections?

Comment: @kevinyu, since you are set column names you can't use SQL parameters. Even you use `String.Format` or `string.Join` you need to validate user input